# jQuery: How to get value from "this" object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made one helper for open new popup window on click and I have a problem with setup default values inside object. I need to calculate position for TOP and LEFT position for popup to center new popup. Here is complete code:

```
/*
    $(element).onPopup(options); - Open Popup window
    -Ths function open new popup window on your browser

    EXAMPLE:
    ----------------------------------------------
    <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>

    $("a#link").onPopup({
        name        :   "Popup Window",
        width       :   800,
        height      :   600
    });

    OPTIONS:
    ----------------------------------------------
    attr            // attribute where is located link
    name            // name of popup window
    width           // max width
    height          // max height
    left            // position left    (px)
    top             // position top (px)
    resizable       // resizable 1 or 0
    location        // display location 1 or 0
    fullscreen      // open in full screen  1 or 0
    scrollbars      // display scroll bars  1 or 0
    titlebar        // display title bar    1 or 0
    toolbar         // display tool bar     1 or 0
    directories     // display directories  1 or 0
*/
$.fn.onPopup=function(options){
    var s   = {
            attr        :   "href",
            name        :   "Popup Window",
            width       :   700,
            height      :   600,
            left        :   ($(window).width()/2)-(this.width/2),
            top         :   ($(window).height()/2)-(this.height/2),
            resizable   :   0,
            location    :   0,
            fullscreen  :   0,
            scrollbars  :   1,
            titlebar    :   0,
            toolbar     :   0,
            directories :   0
        },
        $element    = this;

    s = $.extend(s,options);

    $element.on("click",function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();
        window.open(
            $(this).attr(s.attr), s.name, "width="+s.width+", height="+s.height+", directories="+s.directories+", toolbar="+s.toolbar+", titlebar="+s.titlebar+", scrollbars="+s.scrollbars+", fullscreen="+s.fullscreen+", location="+s.location+", resizable="+s.resizable+", top="+s.top+", left="+s.left
        );
     });
};
```

And here is where is my problem:

```
var s   = {
             /*...*/

                width       :   700,
                height      :   600,
                left        :   ($(window).width()/2)-(this.width/2),
                top         :   ($(window).height()/2)-(this.height/2),

             /*...*/

            },
```

How to pass width/height to another object to work?

Comment: Are you asking how to reference `s.width` from within the same object? So that `this.width === 700`?

Comment: you cannot access the value of another key from within the same object literal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to create the object first then add extra properties that reference other properties in the object

```
var s   = {
        attr        :   "href",
        name        :   "Popup Window",
        width       :   700,
        height      :   600,
        left        :   null, //calculated if not user provided
        top         :   null  //calculated if not user provided
       ....
    };

// update user settings
s = $.extend(s,options);

// calculate based on actual values
if(s.left === null){
   s.left =  ($(window).width()/2)-(s.width/2);
}
if(s.top === null){
   s.top  =  ($(window).height()/2)-(s.height/2);
}
```

Also note you should `return this.each(..` and run your business there so you have separate instances when selector includes more than one element as well as make the plugin chainable with other jQuery methods

Comment: that doesn't allow for the user to specify their own preferred value instead

Comment: @Alnitak sure it does ... `$.extend` takes care of that

Comment: no it doesn't - you're overwriting any value that was passed in `options.left` or `options.top` in the last two lines

Comment: @Alnitak not overwriting anything...it is clear OP wants that as a calculated value ... at least that is my interpretation

Comment: no, it's clear that the OP wants that calculated value as the _default_ position, but also wants the caller to be able to specify a particular value, per the documented `options` in the code comments

Comment: @Alnitak how can *"I need to calculate position for TOP and LEFT position"* not be any clearer

Comment: so, with your version, how exactly would the caller specify `left: 100` (_as permitted by the documented API for this module_) without your code forcing the popup back into the center?

Comment: i do see your point but was going off of what was stated *very clearly* in question

Comment: read the sentence before the bit you quoted - "I have a problem with setup _default values_ inside object"

Comment: Thanks man, yeah, I totaly forget that can be done like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to your API in the code comments you want the caller to be able to specify their own `left` and `top` positions.

You therefore need to check whether any values have been given at all, and only then calculate the default position based on the configured width and height.

```
var s = {
    ... // defaults, *not including* "left" and "top"
};

// override the defaults with the user-supplied options
// NB: no need to re-assign to `s` - `$.extend` overwrites
//     the contents of the first parameter
$.extend(s, options);

// then calculate `left` and `top` if they weren't supplied
if (s.left === undefined) {
    s.left = ($(window).width() - s.width) / 2;
}
if (s.top === undefined) {
    s.top  = ($(window).height() - s.height) / 2;
}
```